# javascript webcam not working in browser

Tags: javascript

i have a webcam script but it doesnt seem to work i also dont get any console errors can some one please help me to see what m i doing wrong

**Photo.js**

```
    (function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
                    vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

 navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                                                                                                                  navigator.WebKitGetUserMedia||
                                                                                                                    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                        navigator.getMedia({
                            video:true,
                            audio:false
                        }, function(stream) {
                            video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                            video.play();
                        }, function(error) {
                            //an error occured
                            //error.code
                        });

    });
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="booth">
     <video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
   </div><!-- end booth -->
```

and here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/heLs62sg/)

This tutorial is script is taken from 
https://youtu.be/gA_HJMd7uvQ?t=456

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Are you sure the camera works/configured?

Comment: yes it is configured , m using chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues at `javascript` at Question. 1) The IIFE is not actually called; you can call the immediately invoked function expression by including opening and closing parentheses `()` before closing parenthesis `)` 2) `w` and `k` at `navigator.WebKitGetUserMedia` should be lowercase characters `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`

```
(function() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || /* substituted `w` for `W`, `k` for `K` */
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

  navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: false
  }, function(stream) {
    video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
    //an error occured
    //error.code
  });   
}()); // added `()` before closing `)`
```

jsfiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/heLs62sg/1/

Comment: i can see it work in ma fiddle but not ma website why 
the current website m working on
http://shahinasingh.esy.es/

Comment: _"i can see it work in ma fiddle but not ma browser why"_ What do mean?

Comment: hmmm please go on to the website above i have the same codes as u have in fiddle but still not working

Comment: it says it has been depreciated ;'( << the console error

Comment: @jake123 Did you review `console` ? `getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See <url> for more details.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111063/discussion-between-jake123-and-guest271314).

Comment: any thought on a fix for this

Comment: Note, `https:` protocol appears to be required, see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins ; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have wrapped this code in a closure which wont run unless you specifically call it from somewhere.

```
(function(){
    // Code will not execute automatically
});
```

Note the extra parenthesis on the final line in the following example:

```
(function(){
    // Code will execute automatically
})();
```

Alternatively, you could assign your code to a variable and manually call it, eg:

```
var func = (function(){
    // Some Code in here
});

func();
```

I suspect that this is the root cause of your problem, but I cant say for sure that your webcam code works but this should be a step in the right direction.