# Serving WebRTC over HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, https, webrtc, getusermedia

`getUserMedia` does not work under simple HTTP in Chrome v47+. Is there any workaround for this, provided the JavaScript code is served from a secure website?

```
<script src="https://example.com/code.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you try instead of posting such simple questions? Stack Overflow is a place where you actually solve programming problems, not where you post a solution ASKING whether it works. You can post a solution and ask why it doesn't work though.

Comment: thanks I edited the question

Comment: I mean actually trying the stuff instead of asking someone else to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia() in chrome 47 without using https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)