# Chrome microphone not working for local files?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

If I go somewhere like this:

```
///Users/Me/Desktop/Part_2/index.html
```

The mic doesn't work (permissions are denied and I'm not asked to turn them on).
Mic does work normally otherwise (going a real website for example).

I tried following the steps here but I don't see how to actually input a new exception it is just a listing with no way to add a new one:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?visit_id=1-636172272435045865-1045688593&p=settings_manage_exceptions&rd=1

Any solutions people have found?

Comment: getUserMedia only works for secure contexts anyway, so you're going to need https. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)

Comment: is it a cross origin problem? audio rarely works running locally.