# why webRTC work by local Lan but not in Internet?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I create a webrtc sample based On [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_video_demo.htm) tutorial. this work on my local network fine and I can send and receive signal and videos. but when I connect from internet ti the server and two peer are not in same network video connection does not create.

I am using self sign Certificate and must add them two browsers.
there is no error or exception. my signaling server is a web socket server written in nodejs.

Comment: what browser are you using? - chrome?

Comment: yes it is chrome in both side

Comment: Please refer to answer below; @navid_pdp11

Comment: Are you using any STUN/TURN servers…?

Comment: Yes i am using a list of stun servers....

Comment: did you verify those servers work? If the turn server credentials say this:
  {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    }
then you'll want to read the note in https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/#after-signaling-using-ice-to-cope-with-nats-and-firewalls

Comment: We need more information. Is the `getUserMedia` step failing (or does self-view work?), or does it fail in the `RTCPeerConnection` step, e.g. you're not getting ICE candidates? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Original Answer**

I believe that you require a HTTPS (SSL certificate) if you are using Chrome +47 to be deployed online, but is not required if serving from a local machine on the same network.

According to caniuse; Edge and Firefox may yield non blocking results (but prefix with moz):http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

[image: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream]

The issue isn't necessarily `WebRTC` but **getUserMedia/Stream API** isn't provided when the called from a non-secure site (or non-localhost address).

Attached Image:
(https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc)

[image: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc]

---

**Update:**
Did a bit more digging around, and the following answer is related to the question [getUserMedia() in chrome 47 without using https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34197653/2903169) i.e. possible **duplicate**;

You "can" launch a Chrome browser to accept the insecure origin; however, that's temp. fix, whereas you'd probably want to get a certificate.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=/test/only/profile/dir --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com"
```

[image]

Comment: would you mean if i create a registered certificate id will work ok? and self sign certificate work only for local peer?

Comment: is there any solution for create ssl cert freely? and for this i must have a domain on my host or i can create ssl for my ip ?

Comment: if you use a registered cert from a registered provider, then chrome will act nicely.

however, if you self sign - chrome will tend to not acknowledge it as "safe". you could try to go via OpenSSL, i need to get back to you on that (as it's not within my own experience in getting that to work).

Comment: If you get Chrome to accept the certificate at all, to open the website at all, then it is *accepted*. Using a CA just automates the process of accepting the certificate, it does not bestow a higher degree of trust than a properly acknowledged self-signed certificate.

Comment: for users who down vote - could you please provide a better answer/feedback on how i can improve the answer;

thanks;