# Webcam doesn't work when uploaded to my site but working on localhost

Tags: javascript, html

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="video-container">
<video id="camera-stream" width="500" autoplay>
</video>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
```

// Normalize the various vendor prefixed versions of getUserMedia.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                        navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                        navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

// Check that the browser supports getUserMedia.

// If it doesn't show an alert, otherwise continue.

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
```

// Request the camera.

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
```

// Constraints

```
{
  video: true
},
```

// Success Callback

```
function(localMediaStream) {
```

// Get a reference to the video element on the page.

```
var vid = document.getElementById('camera-stream');
```

// Create an object URL for the video stream and use this 
// to set the video source.

```
vid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

},
```

// Error Callback

```
function(err) {
```

// Log the error to the console.

```
  console.log('The following error occurred when trying to use getUserMedia: ' + err);
}
 );

} else {
alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
}
}
```

when i run this code in local it does work. But when i upload it to my site which is moneypro.online it only shows my css. why is that?

Comment: Your problem could be that in some browsers like Chrome (since ver 47), `getUserMedia` is allowed only on **https** [See this for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)

Comment: so what should i do sir @ARS81

Answer (score 1):

Open the console of your browser and see if you have a warning like this:

> [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To
>   use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a
>   secure origin, such as HTTPS.

On localhost it could be ok, but `getUserMedia` which is needed for camera access is not allowed on http (at least in Chrome since ver 47), so try to serve your site over **https**

Try to get a valid SSL certificate for your site from here:
https://letsencrypt.org/

Or in your case if you are on HostGator, see their docs for getting SSL:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/acquire-ssl/how-do-i-purchase-an-ssl-and-what-type-is-it

Comment: I don't know how to use it really . >.<

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Moving to https is complex, you must have a valid ssl and you have to set it on the server. In your case I recommend you to get in contact with your provider (HostGator) asking for some help about it. Maybe they have a free testing ssl option which is free and you can easily test it out. Good luck!