# navigator.getUserMedia() without HTTPS?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way this function works with HTTP / Google Chrome?

```
 function getPermisson() {

   navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e){
      __log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });  
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia() in chrome 47 without using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)

Comment: `http://localhost/` only. Also note that `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated. Now use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem!