# Why in Google Chrome does not work recording from a microphone?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, audio-recording

I record audio from a microphone. For it I use  https://github.com/hackingbeauty/react-mic. As written in docs, this library `works via the HTML5 MediaRecorder API (currently only available in Chrome & Firefox)`.

When I run the app in localhost, it works excellent.
But when I tranfered my app to dev-server (http), it works only in Mozila. In Google chrome, when I begin to record I get this error in console:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed`(see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).

Error appear on this string of code.

[image]

My dev-server works via http, maybe google chrome allows using media-record API only for https? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: Try using a Let's Encrypt certificate. It's free.

Comment: In short: yes, all info are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198101/833188)