# Chrome not supporting getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam, secure-context

I have a form in my laravel webapp where the user needs to add a profile picture through webcam. While developing in localhost(secure origin), it was working fine but now when i am trying to access it using my IP address, it doesn't seem to work.

I used "navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia" for accessing webcam while developing my project but now when the website is made live(or testing through my IP), chrome says that "getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins". I also tried Webcam.js but same came across the same error.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
        then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

*Error output in console:*

*[Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.*

Comment: Well the warning says it all- `consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.`. Get an SSL cert, there are some free now if you need one fast (Let's Encrypt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia() in chrome 47 without using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)

Comment: This is nothing to do with Laravel or PHP.

Comment: Need an alternative to getUserMedia() to make webcam input work in insecure origins. Also @HilmiErdemKEREN , edited, saarry :D

Comment: this was done for security reasons so there are no workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost.

did you check this page? I think you're using HTTP. I'd like to switch to HTTPS and test it.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), chrome requires a secure context for using it:

[image]

So you must switch to `https` for testing it in chrome

Comment: Yes i am well aware of that but what else can be done to make the webcam part work in insecure origin?

Comment: @Shiraj were you able to find an insecure alternate ?

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam nope but had used firefox just for that moment. It works in https though.