# Instascan is not working on the js ,showing "Cannot access video stream (TypeError)"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my website to scan QR code.So,I used instascan but it's showing the error "Cannot access video stream (TypeError)" .

My code is given below i.e. app.js ,I checked my camera and had already used other system but not working

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    scanner: null,
    activeCameraId: null,
    cameras: [],
    scans: []
  },
  mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5 });
    self.scanner.addListener('scan', function (content, image) {
      self.scans.unshift({ date: +(Date.now()), content: content });
      document.getElementById("val").value = content;    });
    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
      self.cameras = cameras;
      if (cameras.length > 1) {
        self.activeCameraId = cameras[1].id;
        self.scanner.start(cameras[1]);
      }
      else if (cameras.length > 0) {
        self.activeCameraId = cameras[0].id;
        self.scanner.start(cameras[0]);
      }
       else {
        console.error('No cameras found.');
      }
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    formatName: function (name) {
      return name || '(unknown)';
    },
    selectCamera: function (camera) {
      this.activeCameraId = camera.id;
      this.scanner.start(camera);
    }
  }
});
```

this is the error message on the console

```
app.js:24 Error: Cannot access video stream (TypeError).
    at new i (instascan.min.js:9)
    at Function.<anonymous> (instascan.min.js:9)
    at n (instascan.min.js:4)
    at Generator._invoke (instascan.min.js:4)
    at Generator.e.<computed> [as throw] (instascan.min.js:4)
    at n (instascan.min.js:4)
    at r (instascan.min.js:4)
    at instascan.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ app.js:24
```

this below is the html file

```
</div>
    <div id="app">
            <div class="preview-container">
        <video id="preview"></video>
      </div>
  </div>
        <div class="input-effect">
          <input  class="effect-17" type="text" id= "val" placeholder="Insert code">
        </div>
```

this below is css file

```
#app {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  height: 500px;
  width:100%;
}
.preview-container {
  margin-top: 150px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-left:35%

 /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
input[type="text"]
{font: 40px/60px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; 
color: #333; 
width: 150%; 
box-sizing: border-box; 
letter-spacing: 1px;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-top:none;
border-bottom-color: grey;
background: #FFFAFA;
margin-top:150px;

}

.effect-17
{
  height:100px;
  margin-left:200px;
  width:70%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;

}
```

I know html and css file were not needed but just for sake of convenience,I have uploded it.

Answer (score 6):

Are you able to give the browser permission (or has the browser prompted you to give permission) to access the camera(s)?  Example, in Chrome I was prompted to give the testing site access to the camera, and it now shows in the `allow` listing in `Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Camera`.

Also, the [Instascan ReadMe](https://github.com/schmich/instascan) mentions `Note: Chrome requires HTTPS when using the WebRTC API. Any pages using this library should be served over HTTPS.`  You may want to check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https/34198101#34198101) that discusses how to treat HTTP as secure HTTPS to help with testing in case that is affecting your setup.