# How to prevent a browser for getUsermedia in client server?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, server-side, getusermedia

I have a project that run in local server, i need to record the user audio but the browser not allowed the microphone without https, there have chance to do this in local server without https ? thank you before , and sorry for the bad english language

Comment: This restriction should not apply to `localhost`. Are you sure you run your page from a "local **server**"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getUserMedia() in chrome 47 without using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197653/getusermedia-in-chrome-47-without-using-https)

Comment: no i have client serve , i want the client acces the recording (microphone) without http (because the serve running locally) thats possible to do this?